# Text placement with includes

Tags: php, css

I'm not completely sure how to explain this, but I'll do my best. I am pretty new to this :/

This is my basic template I'm using, I have it as an include, and include it on all my pages.. That all works but, I want to be able to put different text/ stuff in the body area of the template on each page. Right now whenever I add stuff to the page the template body area stays blank, and everything I add just goes below the whole template.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<style>
/* Start CSS */

/* This changes your link colors */
A:link 
{ text-decoration: none; color: #003399; }
A:visited 
{ text-decoration: none; color: #003399; }
A:active
{ text-decoration: none; color: #003399; }
A:hover 
{ text-decoration: none; color: #6666FF; }


/* This changes the basic properties of your layout */
body
{ font-family: Verdana; sans serif; helvetica;
color: #333333;
font-size: 10px;
background-color: #778899;
background-image: url('../ ');
text-align: justify;
margin-bottom: 5px; 
margin-right: 0px; 
margin-top: 5px;
}

/* This code centers the layout */
#container {
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}


/* Leave this be */
#container2 {
width: 1100px;
text-align: left;
margin: 0px auto;
position: relative;
min-height: 300px;
}


/* This code controls the properties of your left menu */
#leftmenu
{ font-family: Verdana; sans serif; helvetica;
color: #333333;
font-size: 10px;
background-color: #E8E8E8;
background-image: url('../ ');
text-align: left;
border: 0px solid #000000;
width:160px;
padding:10px;
}
/* This code controls the link boxes on the sidebars */
a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#98bf21;
width:160px;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#7A991A;
}


/* This code controls the properties of your right menu */
#rightmenu
{ font-family: Verdana; sans serif; helvetica;
color: #333333;
font-size: 10px;
background-color: #E8E8E8;
background-image: url('../ ');
text-align: right;
border: 0px solid #000000;
width:160px;
padding:10px;
}


/* This code is not mandatory, but sets a background for the menu headers */
#menuheader
{ font-family: verdana; helvetica; sans serif;
color: #333333;
font size: 10px;
background-color: #CCCCCC;
background-image: url('../ ');
text-align: center;
margin-top: 5px;
padding:3px;
}

/* This code controls the properties of your content */
#content
{ font-family: Verdana; sans serif; helvetica;
color: #333333;
font-size: 10px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background-image: url('../ ');
border: 0px solid #000000;
padding:10px;
}


/* This code controls the properties of your disclaimer */
#disclaimer
{ font-family: Verdana; sans serif; helvetica;
color: #333333;
font-size: 10px;
background: #CCCCCC;
background-image: url('../ ');
border: 0px solid #000000;
text-align:center;
width:1100px;
height:90px;
padding:10px;
}


/* This code controls the properties of your banner */ 
#banner
{ background: #CCCCCC;
background-image: url('../Images/Banner.png');
border: 0px solid #000000;
text-align:center;
width:1100px;
height:200px;
}


/* This sets the properties for content headers */
h1
{ font-family: verdana; sans serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
font-variant: small-caps;
align:center;
}


/* End CSS */

</style>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="10" bottommargin="10">
<div id="container">
<div id="container2">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr><td valign="top" id="banner" colspan="3"></td></tr>
   <tr>
      <td valign="top" id="leftmenu">

<!-- Start Left Menu -->

         <div id="menuheader">Home</div>
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a>

         <div id="menuheader">Shops</div>
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a>


<!-- End Left Menu-->

      </td>
      <td valign="top" id="content">
         <div align="justify">

<!-- Start Content -->



<!-- End Content -->
</div>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" id="rightmenu">

<!-- Start Right Menu -->

         <div id="menuheader">Ranks</div>
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a>

         <div id="menuheader">Maps</div>
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a><br />
         <a href="#">Link Here</a>

<!-- End Right Menu -->

      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td valign="top" id="disclaimer" colspan="3">

<!-- Start Disclaimer -->

Add disclaimer.

<p>

<!-- End Disclaimer -->

      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know its probably some very simple dumb thing, but I have no idea.

Comment: If i may, where'd you get the template from??

Comment: I don't really remember I just had it in a file for a long time and came across it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP include() means embed the file content. It'll will be parsed according to it's actual order. You need some framework I guess. you cant put some stuff on that body template only by including the file and put the stuff right after that.

Answer (score 0):

well maybe not the best way to do it but it does work.

add `echo body_content();` to the body tags of the main template, then on each page do your content like this

```
function body_content(){
   echo 'simple content';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't continue down this path. Includes are helpful for stuff that you need to repeat on every page, like a footer, sidebar, navigation, header etc. You could copy all that stuff to some includes, but it's going to make much more sense to have seperate .html or .php docs for each page. Or, use a framework like jQuery mobile, but it doesn't sound like your ready for that just yet. Good luck!